# Storing and manage session in MySQL is better than MongoDB?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, performance, session

I'll use the read operation many times.
According to some tests I did, MySQL is fatest in reading one single row than MongoDB. Is it better to use MySQL?
also, i heard someong saying that sometimes is better storing session in files, is it true?

Answer (score -1):

If you tested it and it was faster then why are you not trusting your own research?  You can save the data in a relational database like MySQL, a JSON document store like MongoDB, or a flat file (the flat file may run into i/o contention to open &n read the file).  Go with what you are comfortable with and trust your research.